# JSF Bootsfaces style not reflecting in the pages

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am creating webapplication, which i used bootfaces framework, for this i put `BootsFaces-OSP-dist-0.6.6.jar` file in `WEB-INF\lib` folder. while run my project the webpages displayed without any style. My project code is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">

        <h:head>

        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <b:panel look="primary">
        <f:facet name="heading">Sidebar</f:facet>   
        <b:listLinks>
            <b:navLink header="BootsFaces" />
            <b:navLink href="http://www.bootsfaces.net" value="BootsFaces"
                       icon="globe" iconAlign="right"/>
            <b:navLink></b:navLink>
            <b:navLink header="Bootstrap"/>
            <b:navLink href="http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar" value="Bootstrap" icon="link"></b:navLink>
            <b:navLink></b:navLink>
            <b:navLink header="Preview"/>
            <b:navLink value="Labels and Badges" outcome="/bootstrap/labelsbadge"
                       icon="tag" iconAlign="right"/>
            <b:navLink value="Slider" outcome="/jquery-ui/slider" iconAwesome="sliders" />
        </b:listLinks>
     </b:panel>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

and i configured my web.xml file like,

```
<display-name>Bootfaces</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>

  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

any one suggest me the correct way to solve this issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap theme is disabled by default. Add this to your web.xml.
See: http://www.bootsfaces.net/quick-start.jsf

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>BootsFaces_USETHEME</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I added the line in web.xml file but there is no change, still the css not loaded for the page. any jar file i missed?

Comment: No, you don't need any additional library. Often adding the ```UnmappedResourceHandler``` or the OmniFaces ```CombinedResourceHandler``` fixes resource loading problems (but probably not this one). I suggest you check out one of [my demo projects](https://github.com/stephanrauh/BootsFaces-Examples) to get a working project, and then start to look for differences of the configuration.

Comment: Here is the new link (added a dash between quick and start): http://www.bootsfaces.net/quick-start.jsf